# Load a Joomla menu-item pages into a module position

Tags: php, module, joomla2.5, menuitem, article

With Joomla it's possible to load modules into articles and even into other modules, but is it also possible to load menu-item pages into module positions?

For example, I have a menu item that shows the contact-list, in other words every person added in the contacts in the Joomla backend.

I wish to show this contact-list not as an actual page, but within a module or other article, is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to add a module everywhere in Joomla. Depending where you want to include it there are different approaches.

If you want to add a module in an article you can use the loadmodule placeholder:
    {loadposition xx} //( where xx is the position)

See this for more info http://docs.joomla.org/How_do_you_put_a_module_inside_an_article%3F

Comment: Check the question, Gerb is looking to go the other way. To include an article in a module, not a module in an article.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your contact list is generated within a component, you could also take a different approach by using two plug-ins:

- [Include Component](http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/include-component), and
- [Articles Placed Anywhere](http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/article-placed-anywhere)

Call the non-sef URL to the component from an article using the syntax used by Include Component. Next, call the article within a module using the Articles Placed Anywhere module.

I was looking for an answer to the same question as you, which eventually pulled me in a different direction. I know your question was posted a long time ago, but I thought I'd answer it anyway. Perhaps it's just a partial answer, but I hope it helps.